# Disable Mouse Back button in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: xorg, mouse, input-devices

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit) with my MS mouse. However, I feel the back button of my mouse is so bothersome that I would like to disable that. I googled about this topic but could find any satisfiable answer.

I have tried the steps at Have you check this? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations, but  it seems like to be outdated - Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have any file like `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Any kinds of advice are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but you can use CompizConfig Settings Manager (aka CCSM) to bind mouse buttons. Look under Commands -> Button bindings

Answer (score 0):

`xorg.conf` stopped being used many years ago.  Nevertheless, if it's needed, you can generate it by typing:

`sudo X -configure`

in a terminal window.

This will generate a file named **xorg.conf.new** in your current folder.  As root, you can rename it to **xorg.conf** and move it to your `etc/X11` folder.

`sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`.